# Implementação usando API-Streams e API-Lambda Java 8

Tags: expressões-lambda, java-8, stream

Boa Pessoal.

Tentando sem sucesso resolver um exercício proposto utilizando as novas funcionalidades das APIs Streams e Lambda de java 8. Nesse exercício só é permitido criar e mudar assinatura de métodos na classe CarrinhoCompras. A ideia é utilizar as funcionalidades das APIs Streams e Lambda na resolução.
Alguma ideia  de como posso atacar a resolução?

**CarrinhoComprasFactory**

```
public CarrinhoCompras criar(String identificacaoCliente) {
} 

public BigDecimal getValorTicketMedio() {
}

public boolean invalidar(String identificacaoCliente) {
}
```

**CarrinhoCompras**

```
public void adicionarItem(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {
}

public boolean removerItem(Produto produto) {
}

public boolean removerItem(int posicaoItem) {
}

public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {
}
```

**Produto**

```
public class Produto {

    private Long codigo;
    private String descricao;

    public Produto(Long codigo, String descricao) {
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Item**

```
public class Item {

    private Produto produto;
    private BigDecimal valorUnitario;
    private int quantidade;

    public Item(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema que você está tentando resolver?

Comment: implementar o corpo dos métodos sem mudar a assinatura utilizando as APIs Stream e Lambda

Comment: Não está muito claro o que está querendo fazer.

Comment: A ideia é implementar o corpo dos métodos sem mudar a assinatura deles. Só pode mudar da classe CarrinhoCompras .Também não entendi como resolver, foi um exercício  admissional para uma empresa. Por isso queria escutar opiniões.

Comment: Acho que está faltando informação nesse exercício rsrs

Não vejo como aplicar Stream e Lambda nesse exercício.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível solução a seguir. Não tem arquitetura e desempenho ideais, mas ilustra diversos elementos do Java 8, dentro das restrições do enunciado da questão.

Classe Produto:

```java
package br.teste.compras;

public class Produto {

  private Long codigo;
  private String descricao;

  public Produto(Long codigo, String descricao) {
    setCodigo(codigo);
    setDescricao(descricao);
  }

  // getters and setters omitidos

}
```

Classe Item:

```java
package br.teste.compras;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Item {
  private Produto produto;
  private BigDecimal valorUnitario;
  private int quantidade;

  public Item(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {
    setProduto(produto);
    setValorUnitario(valorUnitario);
    setQuantidade(quantidade);
  }

  public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {
    Multiplicador<Integer> multiplicador = (val1, val2) -> val2.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(val1));
    return multiplicador.multiplicar(getQuantidade(), getValorUnitario());
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  interface Multiplicador<F> {
    BigDecimal multiplicar(F val1, BigDecimal val2);
  }

  //getters and setters omitidos

}
```

Classe CarrinhoCompras:

```java
package br.teste.compras;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CarrinhoCompras {
  private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

  //São admitidas repetições de um mesmo produto.
  //Para uma melhor arquitetura, o valorUnitario deveria ser atributo de Produto.
  public void adicionarItem(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {
    items.add(new Item(produto, valorUnitario, quantidade));
  }

  public boolean removerItem(Produto produto) {
    return items.remove(produto); //retorna true se removido
  }

  public boolean removerItem(int posicaoItem) {
    //Não é a implementação mais eficiente, mas ilustra o uso do Java 8. 
    return items.removeIf(item -> posicaoItem == items.indexOf(item));
  }

  public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {
    return items.stream().map(Item::getValorTotal).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
  }

  //Único método adicionado à classe, conforme permitido pelo enunciado.
  public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
  }

}
```

Classe CarrinhoComprasFactory:

```java
package br.teste.compras;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CarrinhoComprasFactory {
  //Armazena os clientes e seus carrinhos.
  private final Map<String, CarrinhoCompras> map = new HashMap<>();

  public CarrinhoCompras criar(String identificacaoCliente) {
    map.put(identificacaoCliente, new CarrinhoCompras());
    return map.get(identificacaoCliente);
  }

  //Não está clara a função deste método, mas aqui retorna o valor médio dos valores totais nos carrinhos dos clientes.
  public BigDecimal getValorTicketMedio() {
    return map.values().stream()
              .map(carrinho -> carrinho.getValorTotal())
              .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
              .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(map.size()), RoundingMode.FLOOR);
  }

  //Retorna true se existe esse cliente.
  public boolean invalidar(String identificacaoCliente) {
    return map.remove(identificacaoCliente) != null;
  }

}
```

Uma classe para teste, também com alguns elementos do Java 8:

```java
package br.teste.compras;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class Build {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarrinhoComprasFactory factory = new CarrinhoComprasFactory();
        Map<Long, CarrinhoCompras> map = new HashMap<>();
        //Inclui 3 clientes
        LongStream.range(1, 4).forEach(idx -> map.put(idx, factory.criar("Cliente " + idx)));
        //adiciona 3 produtos no carrinho de cada cliente.
        map.forEach((clienteID, carrinho) -> {
            System.out.println("*** Cliente " + clienteID + " ***");
            LongStream.range(1, 4).forEach(idx -> {
                Long random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100);
                carrinho.adicionarItem(
                        new Produto(random * 100, "Produto " +  clienteID * 1000 + idx),
                        BigDecimal.valueOf(random), (int)(random % 11 + 1));
            });
            //imprime os items gerados
            System.out.println(carrinho.getItems().stream()
                    .map(item -> item.getProduto().getDescricao() + "(" + item.getProduto().getCodigo() + "): " +
                            item.getQuantidade() + " x $" + item.getValorUnitario() + " = $" + item.getValorTotal())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        });
        System.out.println("Media clientes 1, 2 e 3: $" + factory.getValorTicketMedio());
        factory.invalidar("Cliente 3");
        map.remove(Long.valueOf(3)); // :-(
        map.get(Long.valueOf(2)).removerItem(1);
        map.get(Long.valueOf(1)).removerItem(map.get(Long.valueOf(1)).getItems().get(0).getProduto());
        System.out.println("Media clientes 1 e 2: $" + factory.getValorTicketMedio());
    }

}
```

Como a construção de valores dos itens é aleatória, abaixo um exemplo de saída impressa pela classe acima (Build):

```
*** Cliente 1 ***
Produto 10001(4400): 1 x $44 = $44, Produto 10002(2700): 6 x $27 = $162, Produto 10003(6900): 4 x $69 = $276
*** Cliente 2 ***
Produto 20001(3500): 3 x $35 = $105, Produto 20002(5200): 9 x $52 = $468, Produto 20003(9500): 8 x $95 = $760
*** Cliente 3 ***
Produto 30001(6700): 2 x $67 = $134, Produto 30002(2800): 7 x $28 = $196, Produto 30003(5000): 7 x $50 = $350
Media clientes 1, 2 e 3: $831
Media clientes 1 e 2: $673
```

Comment: Ótima resposta. Obrigado. Vou marcar como resposta ideal.